# Quando escrevo um comentário aparece o email de todas as pessoas cadastradas. Como faço para aparecer somente meu email que foi logado?

Tags: php

Esse é o código:

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($conexao, "videoaula");

?>

<?php

$sql = "select comentarios.id, comentarios.comentario, usuarios.email from comentarios, usuarios order by id desc";
$executar = mysqli_query ($conexao, $sql);
while ($exibir = mysqli_fetch_array ($executar)){;

echo "<strong>ID:</strong>".$exibir ["email"];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<strong>Comentário:</strong>".$exibir ["comentario"];
echo "<br/><br /><br />";
}

?>
```

Quando executo o codigo, aparece todos os email cadastrados, como abaixo:

```
ID:thaina123
Comentário:olá mundo!!


ID:giovana@hotmail.com
Comentário:olá mundo!!


ID:tayna@gmail.com
Comentário:olá mundo!!


ID:thalia@outlook.com
Comentário:olá mundo!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve salvar o id do usuário na tabela comentários, e ligá-lo no where conforme abaixo:

```
select 
  comentarios.id, 
  comentarios.comentario, 
  usuarios.email 
from comentarios, usuarios
  where comentarios.idusuario = usuarios.id
order by id desc
```

Comment: Olá, agradeço sua resposta! Mas como faço para salvar id do usuario na tabela de comentarios?